# Select doesn't return a value in IE8

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

We have a problem with our select box. If we try to log the selected value, it works fine in chrome and firefox. But in the IE8 it doesn't work. We can't even select a value in the box.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$out2 .= "<select id ='categorySelect' onChange='search(searchKey.value,categorySelect.value)' multiple>";
$out2 .="<option>  All  </option>";
/*  foreach($categoryList AS $category)
    {


        $out2 .= "<option>  $category  </option>";

     } */

     $out2 .= "<option>  IT-Infra  </option>";
     $out2 .= "<option>  IT-HW  </option>";
     $out2 .= "<option>  IT-SW  </option>";
     $out2 .= "<option>  IT  </option>";
  $out2 .=  "</select>";
```

Maybe you can help us.

Comment: where is your "value" in `option` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the `<option>` has a `value`;

Example

```
<option value="IT-Infra">IT-Infra</option>
```

HTML guide - http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option

Answer (score 1):

Meke sure that you have given value in options and
change the onchange function call to:

```
onChange="search($('#searchKey').val(),thi.value)"
or 
onChange="search(document.getElementById('searchKey').value,thi.value)"
```

Answer (score 1):

several problems with your code:

- How did you define the variable `searchKey` and `categorySelect`? You can't just assume that the browser will automatically generate JavaScript variables based on the IDs of elements. You need to query them:

  var searchKey = document.getElementById('searchKey');

In case of `categorySelect` you can just use `this` inside the event handler.

- Older IE don't support `option`  without a `value` attribute.
- Most importantly: That is a `multiple` `select`, so you can't access the selected options with `value`, you need to loop over the options and check which ones are [`selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected).